# Trying to attach to a process to debug a service

Tags: c#

I'm trying to connect to a C# service. I can view the service in Windows Task Manager, but it does not appear in the "Available processes" List. I've tried running VS2012 as my normal user, as administrator, with "Show processes from all users" and Managed (v4.5, v4.0) code instead of the default. The service is built in Debug mode and then installed using an installer(Wix). On every demonstration of this, I've seen "Show Processes In All Sessions"  but this is not shown in my Attach to process dialogue.

I managed to connect from a command line using "vsjitdebugger.exe -p 7012" but this wants to debug in a new instance, and should I use that new instance, I can't see any of the code.

Any advice would be really appreciated.

Comment: If your only goal is to debug a windows service 
http://einaregilsson.com/run-windows-service-as-a-console-program/

Comment: Are you sure you ran as administrator?

Comment: Task manager should show process name/id that hosts your service...

Comment: Yes, I definitely ran VS as administrator. I know that Task Manager can show me the process, that's how I got the 7012 in the above comment. I'm probably going to have to run the program as a console system, but that's not really desirable.